# Expected value of a transformation

Tags: expected-value, random-functions

If $X$ is a continuous random variable with $EX = \mu < \infty$ and $Y = \exp(a|X|)$ for some $a > 0$ Is $EY < \infty$.  How might one go about confirming this? 
Is knowing the distribution of $X$ necessary?

Comment: Is $EX = \mu < \infty$ mean $E(X)$ exists and finite?

Comment: You are correct (I would have just said yes, but there is a 15 character minimum!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible for all $a>0$ 
$$E(Y)=\infty$$

let $X\sim Symmetrized-log-normal(0,1)$

$$
f_X(x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}|x|} e^{-\frac{1}{2} (\log |x|)^2} , \hspace{.5cm} x\in (-\infty , +\infty)
$$
 so $E(X)=0$ and the distribution of $|X|$ is log-normal. [Log-normal_distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution)
in-hence $E(e^{a|X|})$
 equals to Moments generation function of  log-normal that
is infinite for all $a>0$
[existence-of-the-moment-generating-function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32706/existence-of-the-moment-generating-function-and-variance)

so for all $a>0$

$$E(e^{a|X|}) =\infty$$

Comment: Accepting because it's a useful counter example, with a continuous distribution.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for $ E[Y] \rightarrow \infty$

Let $ X= \pm 1.5 $ with probability $ \frac{1}{4} $ (each).
Let $ X= \pm 1.5^2 $ with probability $ \frac{1}{8} $ (each).
Let $ X= \pm 1.5^3 $ with probability $ \frac{1}{16} $ (each).
$\vdots$

Show that $ E[X] = 0 $. (Note, you have to show that the sum converges absolutely.)

Show that $ E[Y] \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: For your example, is X continuous?

Comment: Discrete. $ $ $ $